# Should I include "Follow-up moment" as a fixed factor in my linear mixed model?

Tags: mixed-model, spss, fixed-effects-model, medicine

I am performing a linear mixed model to asses whether pain scores differ between surgically treated patients who tested positive for a bacterial culture versus negative. I have 5 follow up moments but do not know if I should only include the follow up moment as a "repeated measure" or as a fixed factors as well.

As variables I have : Case_Id
Repeated : Followup moment (1,2,3,4 or 5)
Dependent: Pain score
Fixed factor: Bacterial infiltration (yes/no), AGE, BMI
Random factor: Subject (with intercept)

Comment: What is the difference between Case_ID and subject ?

Comment: @BartJonker Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find 
information on how to do this in the **My Account** 
section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually repeated is the case_ID, since you have taken several measures by Case_ID from what I understand. So the Case_ID is the variable which should be a random factor.

If you were to build a linear mixed model, you would need to have one column "follow up moment" containing the values 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. It would mean that you have all the pain scores in the pain score column. From what you describe, it seems that it is what you already have.

I suppose you are interested in the effect of the follow up moment, since you wanted to have it as an explanatory variable. Then the model formula in R should look something like :

```sh
pain score~bacterial infiltration*follow up moment +(1|case_ID)
```

In SPSS unfortunately I cannot say, but the reasoning is the same.
I included an interaction term because the effect of the bacterial infiltration on the pain score might vary according to the follow up moment. I do not know how you would rather include age and BMI, probably as simple effects ?